# Wordpress on Azure App Plan

Tags: wordpress, azure

We created an Azure Wordpress using Wordpress published App. The deployment created 3 things:

1. App Plan
2. App Service
3. Azure Database for MYSQL

Everything is going well, however, we were trying to create a deployment slot. When we created the slot, we select "Clone configuration" from the original app.

Slot was published and ready, however it has nothing, it simply saying welcome to your App service app, etc.

My questions are:

1. Does the deployment slot share the database?
2. Is deployment slot an option for WordPress on Azure?

**Note -** When i ftp to the slot, i am unable to see any content copied.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Clone configuration** only copies App Settings/Connection Strings over. The slot has its own storage, so you need to deploy your WordPress code and content files to the slot as well.

Just treat the slot as a regular Web App - in effect that's exactly what it is - but with the nice feature of being able to easily swap between the two Web Apps (slots).

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing:

> **There is no content after deployment slot creation.** You can deploy to the slot from a different repository branch, or an altogether different repository. You can also change the slot's configuration. Use the publish profile or deployment credentials associated with the deployment slot for content updates. For example, you can publish to this slot with git.